# How do I install package libc6-dev-i386 on fedora?

Tags: c, fedora

When I make yum install libc6-dev-i386 it says no package found, I searched on google and I only found that package for ubuntu or debian.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equivalent will be `glibc-devel`. If you are on a 64-bit `x86_64` system and need to compile 32-bit C programs then you want `glibc-devel.i686`

```
yum install glibc-devel
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a long list of glibc RPMs](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=glibc). Scroll down to Fedora packages and download the version relevant to you.